# Referencing enums in external file in Kaitai Struct

Tags: kaitai-struct

I'd like to have a Kaitai Struct ksy file which references some enums and types in different external files. In the external files there I'd like to have only subtypes and enums definitions.

This is the test file (*test.ksy*) that references the external types:

```
meta:
  id: test
  imports:
    - rowing
  endian: be

seq:
  - id: system_id
    type: u1
  - id: data
    type:
      switch-on: system_id
      cases:
        rowing_messages::position: rowing::rowing_position_message
```

and this is the file (*rowing.ksy*) including the external types:

```
meta:
  id: rowing
  endian: be

enums:
  rowing_messages:
    0x10: position
    0x12: meter_per_stroke

types:
  rowing_position_message:
    seq:
      - id: id
        type: u1
      - id: timestamp
        type: u4
```

The compiler complains:

```
test: /seq/1/type/cases/EnumByLabel(identifier(rowing_messages),identifier(position)): unable to find enum 'rowing_messages', searching from test
```

According to my tests it seems that I can reference the external rowing_position_message type with prefix `rowing::` but I cannot do the same for enums. If I do it like `rowing::rowing_messages::position` the compiler complains:

```
/seq/1/cases/rowing::rowing_messages::position: parsing expression 'rowing::rowing_messages::position' failed on 1:24, expected "or" | CharsWhile(Set( , n)) | "\\\n" | End
```

Thank in advance for any ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prepending `rowing::` is the correct behavior here, as there is no way for a compiler to reference enum declared in the external class except for that.

Also, you'll need to declare `system_id` as enum, not just an integer, by adding

```
enum: 'rowing::rowing_messages'
```

This issue was resolved in relatively modern compiler (i.e. >0.8, any modern 0.9 unstable snapshot should work), so this should work:

```
  - id: system_id
    type: u1
    enum: 'rowing::rowing_messages'
  - id: data
    type:
      switch-on: system_id
      cases:
        'rowing::rowing_messages::position': 'rowing::rowing_position_message'
```

For another option possible with `.to_i` on enums (in theory, you'd rather not use that in practice), please see more in-depth explanation at https://github.com/kaitai-io/kaitai_struct/issues/643.

Comment: I have tested prepending `rowing::` with the 0.9 development version and it works. Thank you.